# how to handle with addTextChangedListener and memory

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-edittext

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText Percent, mmolGlic, mgGlic;

double mmol = 0, mg = 0, perc = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Percent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percent);
    mmolGlic = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mmol_glic);
    mgGlic = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mg_glic);



    /*mmolGlic.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            frommMol();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });*/

    Percent.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            fromPercent();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    /*mgGlic.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            frommg();
        }
    });*/
}

public void frommMol() {
    mmol = Double.parseDouble(mmolGlic.getText().toString());
    perc = (mmol/10.929) + 2.15;
    Percent.setText(String.format( "%.2f", perc ));
}

public void fromPercent(){
    perc = Double.parseDouble(Percent.getText().toString());
    mmol = (perc - 2.15) * 10.929;
    mmolGlic.setText(String.format( "%.2f", mmol ));
    mg = (perc*28.7) - 46.7;
    mgGlic.setText(String.format( "%.2f", mg ));
}

public void frommg(){
    mg = Double.parseDouble(mgGlic.getText().toString());
    perc = (mg + 46.7) / 28.7;
    Percent.setText(String.format( "%.2f", perc ));


}
```

}

Goodmorning everyone :)

this is a continuous question from this one: [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051486/how-to-change-text-in-a-textview-dynamically-based-on-another-textview)

this an example code of what i'm trying to do. But i have some problems. I think most of them are for the logic of variables and how to handle the input in more EditTexts. for example:

1. the main problem is that i can't use more than one addTextChangedListener. I try to explain better: if i leave the code as here, the app crashes. I am not sure, maybe it's due to how i handle the three EditTexts.
2. then i have a problem when i delete the text: if i have "5.99" and i
   press del, when it's deleting it deletes until the 5 and then
   crashes. Probaly i should set when the text field is empty the
   variables = 0.

can you help me? thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText Percent, mmolGlic, mgGlic;

double mmol = 0, mg = 0, perc = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Percent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percent);
    mmolGlic = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mmol_glic);
    mgGlic = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mg_glic);

 Percent.addTextChangedListener(percentWatcher);
        mmolGlic.addTextChangedListener(mmolGlicTextWatcher);
        mgGlic.addTextChangedListener(mgGlicWatcher);
}

 public void frommMol() {
        if (!mmolGlic.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            mmol = Double.parseDouble(mmolGlic.getText().toString());
            perc = (mmol / 10.929) + 2.15;
            Percent.removeTextChangedListener(percentWatcher);
            Percent.setText(String.format("%.2f", perc));
            Percent.addTextChangedListener(percentWatcher);
        }
    }

    public void fromPercent() {
        if (!Percent.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            perc = Double.parseDouble(Percent.getText().toString().trim());
            mmol = (perc - 2.15) * 10.929;
            mmolGlic.removeTextChangedListener(mmolGlicTextWatcher);
            mgGlic.removeTextChangedListener(mgGlicWatcher);
            mmolGlic.setText(String.format("%.2f", mmol));
            mg = (perc * 28.7) - 46.7;
            mgGlic.setText(String.format("%.2f", mg));
            mmolGlic.addTextChangedListener(mmolGlicTextWatcher);
            mgGlic.addTextChangedListener(mgGlicWatcher);
        }
    }

    public void frommg() {
        if (!mgGlic.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            mg = Double.parseDouble(mgGlic.getText().toString());
            perc = (mg + 46.7) / 28.7;
            Percent.removeTextChangedListener(percentWatcher);
            Percent.setText(String.format("%.2f", perc));
            Percent.addTextChangedListener(percentWatcher);
        }
    }


    private TextWatcher percentWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            fromPercent();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    };

    private TextWatcher mgGlicWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            frommg();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    };

    private TextWatcher mmolGlicTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                frommMol();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    };

}


Hope this will help you.
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Can you explain me what have you done? Just to understand it better

Comment: I have created 3 textwatcher for all 3 edittext seperately. And From each calculation methods, I make calculations first, then remove other textwatcher before setting text to edittext because if i won't remove textwatcher and setText to edittext then it will start calling recursively each other.  And then again i have set textwatcher listener to those which i have removed previously to it works usually as before.

Comment: ahh okay. I ask you the last thing: when i delete values from one editText how can i delete values from other?

Comment: You can check length in onTextChanged , so when you got length 0 clear edittext for other two.

Comment: it's still crashing

Comment: Which Exception it gives ?

Answer (score 0):

well what it looks like, that you are doing your operation even if you don't have any text to work with.. i would recommend, do a null/empty check on the editTextView before you do thefromPercent(); operation. Hope that helps.

Comment: something like checking if the EditText is empty, "", variables = 0 (?)

Comment: yes.. something like this.    if((! Percent.getText().toString().isEmpty())&&(Percent.getText().toString()!=null)){  // do your work}

Comment: it works. But if I use the addTextChangedListsener for all of three EditText it crashes. Maybe it's because it does operations during values change for every EditText. I don't know if I explained good.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702771/how-to-use-single-textwatcher-for-multiple-edittexts

Comment: @androidCoder-BD thank you very much. It's still crashing. I have some problems in, after deleting a value from an editText, how to set variables's value to 0